# automorphic form associated with Apollonian Gasket

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

In /Indra's Pearls/, it's mentioned one can associate automorphic forms with limit sets. Is there an explicit description of the one associated with the Apollonian gasket (up to some appropriate discrete subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$).

the Poincaré series or an infinite product would suit my purposes

Comment: a bit pessimistic from Elena Fuchs: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~efuchs/FuchsStrongApprox.pdf

Comment: I get it: her dissertation was 2010, her Bulletin article was April 2013. Kontorovich article on thin orbits in the same issue.